Bound for expected value of the maximum of $X^2$ and $Y^2$
problem: If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$, define $\rho = \text{Cov}[X, Y]$. Proof that
$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(X^2, Y^2)] \leq 1 + \sqrt{1 - \rho^2}.
$$
my try: We know that $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2] = 1$ and $\rho = \text{Cov}[X, Y] = \mathbb{E}[XY]$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\max(X^2, Y^2)] &= \frac12 \mathbb{E}[X^2 + Y^2 + |X^2 - Y^2|] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left( \mathbb{E}X^2 + \mathbb{E}Y^2 + \mathbb{E}[|X^2 - Y^2|] \right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[|X^2 - Y^2|] \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[|(X - Y)(X + Y)|].
\end{align*}
Then I want to show that $\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E}[|(X - Y)(X + Y)|] \leq \sqrt{1 - \mathbb{E}[XY]^2}$, following the above path.

The follows from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\E\left[\left\vert (X-Y)(X+Y)\right\vert\right] \leq \sqrt{\E\left[\left\vert X-Y\right\vert^2\right] \E\left[\left\vert X+Y\right\vert^2\right]} = \sqrt{(2-2\rho)(2+2\rho)}=2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}.
$$
